# expected expression before 'Tpunto1'

Tags: array, c

El programa lo que tendria que hacer es: tomar un par de valores x,y para cada Tpunto y dar la distancia entre ambos puntos.
Es decir, pide los puntos de x1 e y1, los mete detro de Tpunto1, desp los x2 e y2 y los mete dentro de Tpunto2. Luego con funciones tengo que dar la distancia entre ambos. (tuve que escribir mas ya que no me dejaba publicarlo)

Realmente no se en que me estoy equivocando, supongo que en la forma en que cree el array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

typedef struct{
    int x1,y1;
}Tpunto1; 
Tpunto1 punto1;
typedef struct{
    int x2,y2;
}Tpunto2;
Tpunto2 punto2;

int distanciaX, distanciaY, distancia;
void main(){
    printf("Ingresar x1: ");
    scanf("%i", &punto1.x1);
    printf("Ingresar y1: ");
    scanf("%i", &punto1.y1);
    printf("Ingresar x2: ");
    scanf("%i", &punto2.x2);
    printf("Ingresar y2: ");
    scanf("%i", &punto2.y2);

    int distanciaX(punto1.x1, punto2.x2);
    int distanciaY(punto1.y1, punto2.x2);

    printf("%i", distancia(distanciaX, distanciaY));

}

int distanciaX (Tpunto1.x1, Tpunto2.x2){    
    int resutaldoX;
    resultadoX = pow(Tpunto.x2-Tpunto1.x1, 2);
//distanciaY = pow(Tpunto2.y2-Tpunto1.y1),2)
//distancia = sqrt(pow((Tpunto2.x2-Tpunto1.x1),2)+(pow(Tpunto2.y2-Tpunto1.y1),2));
    return resultadoX;  
}

int distanciaY(Tpunto.y1, Tpunto.y2){
    resultadoY = pow(Tpunto2.y2-Tpunto1.y1),2);
    return resultadoY; 
}

int distancia(distanciaX, distanciaY){
    resultadoDist = sqrt(distanciaX + distanciaY);
    return resultadoDist;
}
```

Comment: Hay muchos errores, los nombres de las funciones coincide con los nombres de las variables globales que definiste. Además estás tomando `Tpunto2` como si fuera una variable, cuando en realidad es el tipo. Más bien, deberías definir la variable de esta forma: `struct Tpunto2 miPunto;`

Comment: listo! ya cambie los nombres de la variables globales con las de las funciones y defini Tpunto1 en punto1 y Tpunto2 en punto2 y agregue esto al codigo 
    int distanciaX(punto1.x1, punto2.x2);
    int distanciaY(punto1.y1, punto2.x2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al hacer:

```
typedef struct{
   ...
}Tpunto1;
```

`Tpunto2` es el nombre del tipo (`typedef`), cuando haces  `scanf("%i", &Tpunto.x1)` es como si intentas algo como  `scanf("%i", &int)`. Debes crear dos variables a partir del tipo definido como estructura.

Aparte de ésto:

- No tiene sentido que definas un tipo para cada punto, define un tipo `Tpunto` y úsalo para representar ambos puntos.
- La función `main` para cumplir con el estándar debe retornar un entero siempre.
- En la línea:

  ```
   int distanciaX, distanciaY, distancia;
  ```

  no se si pretendes declarar las variables que luego usas en la función o las propias funciones, si es lo primero para empezar no debes dar el mismo nombre a las funciones y  a las variables, de cualquier forma no hay necesidad alguna de declararlas globalmente.

  Lo que si tienes que declarar son las funciones, a no ser que las definas antes de `main`.
- No estás definiendo correctamente los parámetros de tus funciones.

  - Si piensas pasar el propio struct:

    ```
    int distanciaX(Tpunto punto1, Tpunto punto2);
    int distanciaY(Tpunto punto1, Tpunto punto2);
    int distancia(int, int);
    ```
  - Si quieres pasar un puntero al struct:

    ```
    int distanciaX(Tpunto *punto1, Tpunto *punto2);
    int distanciaY(Tpunto *punto1, Tpunto *punto2);
    int distancia(int, int);
    ```
- En principio sería más lógico que tus distancias fueran de tipo `double` y no `int`.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>


typedef struct{
    int x, y;
}Tpunto;


double distanciaX(Tpunto, Tpunto);
double distanciaY(Tpunto, Tpunto);
double distancia(double, double);


int main(void){
    Tpunto punto1;
    Tpunto punto2;
    printf("Ingresar x1: ");
    scanf("%i", &punto1.x);
    printf("Ingresar y1: ");
    scanf("%i", &punto1.y);
    printf("Ingresar x2: ");
    scanf("%i", &punto2.x);
    printf("Ingresar y2: ");
    scanf("%i", &punto2.y);
    double distX = distanciaX(punto1, punto2);
    double distY = distanciaY(punto1, punto2);
    printf("%f", distancia(distX, distY));
    return 0;
}

double distanciaX (Tpunto p1, Tpunto p2){    
    double distanciaX = pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2);
    return distanciaX;  
}

double distanciaY(Tpunto p1, Tpunto p2){
    double distanciaY = pow((p1.y - p2.y), 2);
    return distanciaY; 
}

double distancia(double distanciaX, double distanciaY){
    double distancia = sqrt(distanciaX + distanciaY);
    return distancia;
}
```

Dado que antes lo mencionaba, pasando un puntero a estructura en vez del propio `struct` podrías hacer:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>


typedef struct{
    int x, y;
}Tpunto;


double distanciaX(Tpunto *, Tpunto *);
double distanciaY(Tpunto *, Tpunto *);
double distancia(double, double);


int main(void){
    Tpunto punto1;
    Tpunto punto2;
    printf("Ingresar x1: ");
    scanf("%i", &punto1.x);
    printf("Ingresar y1: ");
    scanf("%i", &punto1.y);
    printf("Ingresar x2: ");
    scanf("%i", &punto2.x);
    printf("Ingresar y2: ");
    scanf("%i", &punto2.y);
    double distX = distanciaX(&punto1, &punto2);
    double distY = distanciaY(&punto1, &punto2);
    printf("%f", distancia(distX, distY));
    return 0;
}

double distanciaX (Tpunto *p1, Tpunto *p2){    
    double distanciaX = pow(p1->x - p2->x, 2);
    return distanciaX;  
}

double distanciaY(Tpunto *p1, Tpunto *p2){
    double distanciaY = pow((p1->y - p2->y), 2);
    return distanciaY; 
}

double distancia(double distanciaX, double distanciaY){
    double distancia = sqrt(distanciaX + distanciaY);
    return distancia;
}
```